# Shopify Product Page metafield value retrieval

Tags: shopify

I have added metafields to products and in that I have added goldpurity and diamond weight to which i am giving values as 18KT and 0.23c.
but when I am tying to retrieve the value with `{{ product.metafields.custom.goldpurity}}` or `{{ product.metafields.custom.goldpurity. Value }}` it shows me
`{"type":"root","children":\[{"type":"paragraph","children":\[{"type":"text","value":"18KT"}\]}\]}`

I want to retrieve 18KT value
I have tried the following

```
{% assign gold_purity_obj = gold_purity_json | parse %}
{% assign gold_purity_value = gold_purity_obj.children\[0\].children\[0\].value %}

<p>{{ gold_purity_value }}</p>
```

still it doesn't work

Comment: What type is the metafield?

Comment: its a single line text

Comment: If it's a json use json object then

Answer (score 0):

This got me the value:

```
{% assign metafield = product.metafields.custom.goldpurity.value %}
{% if metafield %}
  <p>{{ metafield }}</p>
{% endif %}
```